# One-liner object comprehension in python3

Tags: python

```
names = ""
for p in portals: names = names + str(p)
```

Ie there a one-liner pythonic-way to achieve this ?

Comment: `"".join(str(p) for p in portals)` or `"".join(map(str, portals))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method:

```
"".join(str(p) for p in portals)
```

Do note that there is even a more pythonic way to write

```
names = names + str(p)
```

and that way is

```
names += str(p)
```

Comment: instead of `str(p) for p in portals` you can do `map(str, portals)` but of course then it's no longer a list comprehension.

Comment: @vaizki Yes, but I think you mean generator :)